# I can't figure out why this value calculates in one function but not the other

Tags: c++, function, class

Hi I'm new and I've been working on this Blackjack program for a while now, I've been trying to make simple games like this to practice. I'm just about finished but I've run into a small problem that's been making me go crazy all night. There's a Game, Player, Deck, and Card class. I'll try to post just the relevant code, I really don't want to make it long and hard to read. I think just these functions in the Game class explain the problem.

Game.cpp:

```
void Game::createPlayers(int p) //creates p players and stores in players vector
{
    for (int x = 0; x < p; x++)
    players.push_back(Player(x + 1));
}

void Game::startRound() //deals 2 cards to each player and prints their hand
{

    dealer.hit(deck.draw());
    dealer.hit(deck.draw());
    cout << "Dealer's hand: " << endl << "Face down card" << endl;

    dealer.printDealer();

    for (int x = 0; x < players.size(); x++)
    {
        players[x].hit(deck.draw());
        players[x].hit(deck.draw());

        players[x].calcTotal();
        cout << "Total: " << players[x].getTotal() << endl;
        cout << "Player " << players[x].getSeat() << "'s hand:" << endl;
        players[x].printHand();
    }
}

void Game::playerChoice(Player x) //while user enters 1, keeps adding cards to hand
{
    int action = 0;
    x.calcTotal();
    if (x.getTotal() == 21)
    {
        cout << "Player " << x.getSeat() << " has a blackjack!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Player " << x.getSeat() << "'s turn: 1 to hit, 2 to stay: ";
        cin >> action;
    }

    while (action == 1)
    {
        cout << endl;
        x.hit(deck.draw());
        x.calcTotal();
        x.printHand();

        if (x.getTotal() == 0)
        {
            cout << "Player " << x.getSeat() << " has busted\n\n";
            action = 2;
        }

        if (action == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter 1 to hit again, 2 to stay: ";
            cin >> action;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Player " << x.getSeat() << "'s total: " << x.getTotal() << endl;
}

void Game::collectWinnings() //compares the player's hand total to the dealer's
{
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
            players[i].calcTotal();
        if (players[i].getTotal() > dealer.getTotal())
        {
            cout << "Player " << players[i].getSeat() << " wins." << endl;
                players[i].winBet();
        }
        else if (players[i].getTotal() < dealer.getTotal())
        {
            cout << "Player " << players[i].getSeat() << " loses." << endl;
            players[i].loseBet();
        }
        else
            cout << "Player " << players[i].getSeat() << " ties." << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm really sorry if it's too messy or too much. My problem is that in collectWinnings(), when I use calcTotal() then getTotal() it always returns only the total from the initial 2 cards they were given in startRound(). However, if I use calcTotal() then getTotal() at the end of playerChoice() it returns the total of the entire hand. Somehow it doesn't count the entire hand when I do it in collectWinnings(). Is there a reason for this? Am I trying to do something that C doesn't allow?

Answer (score 1):

In `Game::playerChoice(Player x)`, you are passing Player `x` by value. In other words, a local copy is created for the duration of the function. As the control returns to the caller, the changes (e.g. the new cards added to the player's deck) are lost since they were not made on the *original* `Player` instance (the one stored in the `players` vector used in `startRound()` and `collectWinnings()`).

To avoid this problem, you could pass the Player by reference:

```
void Game::playerChoice(Player & x)
//                            ^^^
```

changes made to `x` are then made on the original `Player` instance in the caller scope. So, if you were calling `playerChoice` in something such as:

```
void Game::allPlayersChoice()
{
  for (int x = 0; x < players.size(); x++)
  {
    playerChoice(players[x]);
  }
}
```

Then the `Player` instances `players[x]` of the `Game` object would be updated. Since `collectWinnings()` also uses those *same* `players[x]` instances, the calls to `players[i].calcTotal()` in `collectWinnings()` would then be done on an updated Player, which would account for the entire hand.

Comment: Would I need to change anything in the coding? For example, when I call x.calcTotal() would that need to be changed somehow?

Comment: @bucky: I've updated the answer to clarify the effect of passing by reference. But short answer, no you would not need to change anything else.